# Remove strange code from wordpress footer

Tags: plugins

I found strange code in footer on view source of web page.

```
<span style="position: absolute; visibility:collapse; font-size:30% "> 
<h2>sites darknet france</h2><p>
Les sites darknet les plus populaires sont probablement les fameux 
nombreux sites de trading en ligne anonymes. Ici, vous pouvez acheter et vendre nimporte quoi: les médicaments strictement interdits sont commandés ici en un clic, ils paient avec la crypto-monnaie Bitcoin et sont livrés directement sous la porte. Afin décrire mon livre, Darknet, jai passé beaucoup de temps sur ces sites à essayer de comprendre comment et pourquoi ils travaillent. Jai même expérimenté le processus dachat dune petite quantité de cannabis sur un site Web appelé <a href="https://darknetreview.example.is/berlusconi-market/">darknet market reviews</a>
```

(`.example` added to disarm the link.)

This code is added by *wp_footer()* function. I have checked function.php , footer.php and try deactivating all plugin one by one, but the reason of this code not found.

Please suggest any solution.

Comment: Probably your site was hacked. Restore from a known-good backup. Please don't post links to malicious sites.

Answer (score 0):

There is a WP hack (probably several) that will modify the footer, usually by modifying the active theme code. Completely delete that theme (via your hosting File Manager), then reinstall the theme from the WP repository.

And, since your site was hacked, there are probably (most likely) other areas of your site that need to be 'de-hacked'. Lots of help on the googles (and here, although hacked sites is not within allowable questions here) on how to de-hack a WP site.

Change all credentials (hosting, ftp, WP admin, database); inspect all files for added code, reinstall all themes/plugins from known good sources, update everything, and more.